# Getting the URL when webViewDidStartLoad is called?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos, uiwebview

If I try to retrieve the URL from the webView when my webViewDidStartLoad method is called, I get an empty string. Here's my code:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSURL* url = [webView.request URL];    
    const char* urlchar = [[url absoluteString] UTF8String];

    // do stuff with urlchar...
}
```

It's the same code I use in webViewDidFinishLoad and that seems to work. Is that the correct method? Is there a better way? Should I expect to get a valid url when it's called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the correct way. The `webView` argument provided in that delegate method allows you to access the `UIWebView` that started the request. As a side note, this method is called when images, scripts, and other resources in the page are loaded (once per resource). To make sure the page is completely finished, check the `loading` property.

Comment: I know you say this is the correct way, but I'm seeing the same thing as the OP... the URL is empty. Is this a bug?

Comment: Try using `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`.

Comment: Well, I want to show a waiting UIActivityIndicatorView, so I am trying to start that indicator in the webViewDidStartLoad method. and I also have a url.query string to judge whether need a that indicator.